# Unsigned int And Signed int in C

Tags: c

**How the compiler knows that the data type is a unsigned int or signed int if we declared a variable with signed integer type or unsigned integer type **

Comment: Is that a question?

Comment: Yes, September is early this year.

Comment: All compilers have a built-in crystal ball which they use in situations like this.

Answer (score 3):

are you asking how the **compiler** knows?  It knows because you've declared it that way.

When you're declaring the variable with a type, you're explicitly telling the compiler the type of that variable.

Answer (score 2):

you declare it with the `signed` or `unsigned` keyword.

Comment: Actually, I don't think I ever saw someone explicitly using the `signed` keyword for anything different than `char`s (well, personally I didn't even see a `signed char` in the wild, but that's probably the only sensible use case for `signed`).

Comment: I agree to your point Sir. But the OP's question is a bit wiered to get to that point.!! ;)

Comment: I know, honestly I'd say that my comment was just nitpicking for the sake of it :)

Comment: Cheers!!! Fully Agree +1..

Answer (score 1):

If you write "unsigned int i;" the compiler knows "i" is a unsigned int.

If you write "int i;" or "signed int i;", the compiler knows "i" is a signed int.

C data types:
http://www.lix.polytechnique.fr/~liberti/public/computing/prog/c/C/CONCEPT/data_types.html